# Getting CoreBluetooth to detect a device a second time

Tags: bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

I'm working on an app that's scanning for a specific BLE device to come on the air, using CoreBluetooth. The device comes on the air and is read and interacted with. My problem is, when the device is unplugged and plugged back in a few minutes later, the `didDiscoverPeripheral` delegate method does not get called again. I've specified the 'allow duplicates' option via this code:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE],@"CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", nil];
```

Is there any way to get the `didDiscoverPeripheral` method to be fired each time that module comes on the air, no matter how soon after it disappeared? Does anybody have an idea of what the 'timeout' is between device disconnection and when the CoreBluetooth manager will see it again?

Comment: Do you need to connect to the 'specific' BLE device? Or do you just need to scan for the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your Code:

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE],@"CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey", nil];
```

This code is using literal NSString @"CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey" as a key but not the actual key.

Should be :

```
NSDictionary *options = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:[NSNumber numberWithBool:TRUE],CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey, nil];
```